# Powerapps Copy Paste function for a Group

Tags: copy-paste, powerapps, create-function

I want to copy & paste groupped items. 
When I click on a button, I want that the groupped items will be created/ copy pasted is there any possibility ?

Exp:
I have a orginal 1x textinputbox, 1x dateinput, 1x numberinput, 1x label. I want to copy and paste the copys under the orginals when I click on a button.
Is there any possibility to create these elements with a button somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think PowerApps supports copy/paste of grouped items today. You can copy/paste a control. There are some known limitations with this functionality: copying screens, data sources, and referenced controls is not supported. To read more, please refer to https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/copy-and-paste-controls-across-canvas-apps-available/